# Imperative + which, should

Tags: word-order, modal-verbs, imperatives

I'm about to post an ad for our company survey but I'm not sure which of the following (the position of *should*) is correct.

> Take the survey on which computer *should* our company get next.

or

> Take the survey on which computer our company *should* get next.

Comment: The second is correct and the first isn't. But you might want to consider getting a native English speaker in the ad and survey departments, if the ads and the surveys are sposta be in English.

Comment: Take the survey to help the company choose which computer we should buy. Though people usually put should before the pronoun only in questions, some people do say "I don't know what should I buy", but "I don't know what I should buy" is more commonly used. Also "take a survey on" is not very common,  "a survey about" sounds more natural

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically (and semantically), OP's sentences are equivalent to...

> 1: *Vote on which computer should we get*
>    2: *Vote on which computer we should get*

...which we can easily convert to something common enough to search for on Google Books...

> 3: *Tell me what should I do* [(11,200 results)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tell%20me%20what%20should%20I%20do%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    4: *Tell me what I should do* [(99,700 results)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tell%20me%20what%20I%20should%20do%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

So if you believe there's safety in numbers, go for the second version.

---

Look at some of the results for #3 above and you'll see they often have any or all of these features...

1 - a comma or colon after *Tell me*
2 - the words after *Tell me* enclosed in quotes
3 - the word *Which* capitalised
4 - a question mark at the end

That's because the text after *Tell me* (after *Take the survey on* in OP's example) ***is a question***.

Note that both forms are perfectly valid, and unproblematic in *speech*. But in *writing* OP will have to address punctuation. As there's no single "correct" written form, whatever choice he makes will seem "wrong" to some people. So that's another reason to avoid the first version.